# Which loss funtion should i use in Regression problems?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, loss-functions

i want to know that which loss function should i use in regression problems.In most of the cases i saw MSE and MAE.which one is better to monitor ?. Also I want to know that the loss functions which i mentioned is suited to which type of regression problems?.

Comment: The choice of loss function depends completely on your objective and data, it is hard for me to tell you a simple rule when to use which. MSE works well in most cases, MAE may work well in case of outliers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link may help: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-choose-loss-functions-when-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/

From there: "The Mean Squared Error, or MSE, loss is the default loss to use for regression problems.

Mathematically, it is the preferred loss function under the inference framework of maximum likelihood if the distribution of the target variable is Gaussian. "

Mean absolute error may be appropriate if the outliers should be weighted linearly. This is frequently the case if you can assign a monetary value. A €10 loss is twice as large as a €5 loss, not four times as large.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the probability distributions of the errors, unexplained differences between your model and the observed data. MSE is appropriate when you expect the errors to be normally distributed. This is due to the square term in the exponent of the Gaussian density function:

$$
f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} e^{-(x-\mu(x))^2 / (2 \sigma^2) }
$$

Minimising MSE is equivalent to maximising the likelihood of the parameters.

MAE implies exponential distribution of absolute errors.